# Why does the differential amplifier not need capacitors at the input?

Tags: amplifier, bjt

Why does the differential amplifier not need capacitors at the input?
I've seen other amps with BJT as a common emitter, common base, etc; and these do have a capacitor at their input.

[image: not capacitor at the input]

Comment: How would you measure DC values with capacitors at the input?

Comment: I have never seen such a differential pair. First, the output of the current mirror (dynamic load) should be taken from the Q1's collector (not from the Q2's collector as shown). Then, what is the purpose of the two separate current sources in the Q1 and Q2 emitters? And finally, what are these 10 k base resistors for?

Comment: Do you know why the other amplifiers need a DC-block capacitor? Because that's where you should be looking first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This circuit is dc coupled and is meant to work all the way to dc.

Comment: I don't understand, can you please detail more

Comment: If you have a capacitor in series with the signal path, there will always be a low frequency cut-off below which the gain will become very small. This is because the impedance of a capacitor increases a 1/f.  Circuits that are designed to work all the way down to zero frequency cannot have capacitors in series with the signal path.

Comment: I understand thank you

Answer (score 4):

This has a bipolar supply with a 0V reference suitable for DC input.

If a 0V reference sine input was applied to a single supply Op Amp, then a series cap is needed to avoid saturating the output to 0V, using this inverting input.

If using non-inverting input then a differential configuration could be used with a reference to Vcc/2 to create an offset to the output and still have DC coupling as long as the Vcm input range is satisfied.

[e.g. simulation](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDOB0YzCsICMZICYaoOyYMxgByoBsAnCZiHBQnBHAKYC0iiAUAIYir75ImogALDgGJ%20IXogQRksGEMhkSIklUT4wRYSQVLBqVXHw5y%20TAlmxWAdy48kiAd0mYi4G0JF8Bw0Y-cATnaS-r4OAjJyrEHOXATBXHBukVYx9uiS4hngSFEA8p6i4oIkbmIR7gBK3nGSRBDZMiD1lDkQKHCsAOY1LEWiLe2s1bGoSSAiDePtQnRtUJ1pIf3hOZZgrIJgOCClXFtcqIITYMcQmAD6WhdgF8JwghdwN5CINxeoF5c4m9sT%20McjnR-Hgzs0ro9bvdHsgXm9bmwgA) using a CMOS rail to rail type.

Answer (score 1):

Capacitor is used for eliminating the DC part. Besides if the power supply of the amplifier is unipolar but the input signal is bipolar, the circuit won't work. Your amplifier is powered by +-vcc, and hence you don't need capacitor at input.